# celery: how to read celery beat config from django settings?

Tags: python, django, celery

The celery app has function a `config_from_object` which I use to load configurations from the Django settings:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

But with such namespace celery only load settings that starts with `CELERY_` and ignores: `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY`, `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER`, etc.

Comment: What is your question? Change the `namespace` to `CELERYD`...

Comment: how to read celery beat config from django settings?

Comment: if I change namespace then other settings will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Removing `namespace` kwarg solved the problem.

Another solution is to change config prefixes:

```
CELERYD -> CELERY_WORKER
CELERYBEAT -> CELERY_BEAT
```